# get last updated value like last inserted id SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get  last updated value like we get last inserted value using mysql function : `mysqli_insert_id($conn)` ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: You can't get the last updated row unless you maintain a `timestamp` field in the table that get auto updated on every update of a row.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty for what?

Comment: the above function will give you the last effected rows when you run an update command.